# How to write all rows using fuzzy wuzzy python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I have a `list = ['NAAR HUIS', 'TIANJIN', 'GORINCHEM', 'TIMIKA0', 'DAMMAM', 'DULAC', 'SUNDERLAND']`
and want to compare the each element of the list with the column 3 of the given csv file using fuzzy wuzzy. if the string is match greater than 80% then it will save the row to a new csv file.

csv file

[image]

follwing is the sample for one string. How can i do it for the list item mentioned above

```
def get_ratio(row):
    name = row[3]
    name1 = 'JANGMEN'   
    return fuzz.token_sort_ratio(name, name1)
df = df[df.apply(get_ratio, axis=1) > 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it to get the best match. If you compare each element in the list to each row, you will be using a nested loop + fuzzy, which will be computationally expensive. Using fuzzy immediately while looping over your list be will be more efficient. Then, you can decide whether to keep it if it exceeds the 80%.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process
def get_ratio(df):
   col_names = df[3].tolist()
   for name in list:
       result = process.extractOne(name, col_names, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
       if result[1] >= 80:
            # Filter data frame to get the retrieved row
            filtered_df = df[df[3] == result[0]]
            # Create a new data frame with same header first
            new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[your current header columns])
            new_df.append(filtered_df)
```